# Multiple package in a single go module

Tags: go, module, project

[image]

I am very new to GO. Trying to understand how to structure my project inside a go module.

As you can seen in the screen shot , I have one go module .
Inside I have main.go . Following is the content.

```
package main

import "go-test/repo/test"

func main() {
    test.GetFun()
}
```

Inside repo/test.go , following is the content.

```
package repo

import "fmt"

// GetFun just for fun
func GetFun() {
    fmt.Println("fun")
}
```

When I run , `go build`  following is the error I get .

```
   maing.go:3:8: package go-test/repo/test is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/go-test/repo/test)
```

Comment: Your `test.go` defines the package `repo`, so you should import it like `import "go-test/repo"`, and in `main` refer to it as `repo`, not as `test`, like `repo.GetFun()`. Please read [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html).

Comment: Also the above assumes your module path is `go-test` (this must be reflected by `go.mod`).

Comment: Thanks . it worked for me.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> Your test.go defines the package repo, so you should import it like
> import "go-test/repo", and in main refer to it as repo, not as test,
> like repo.GetFun(). Please read [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html).

– icza